# Dist-upgrade command leads to black screen

Tags: upgrade, kali-linux, sudo, black-screen-of-death

I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y` on kali linux
Then I cannot even login in my machine. There is a black screen with blinking cursor.
**How do I solve this thing? I don't want to install My Kali Linux again, please.**

Comment: Is there a terminal login prompt top left?  Try restarting to see if this prompt comes up.

Comment: Ctrl-alt-F1 or Ctrl-alt-F2 may give you a tty console login.  BTW, I thought Kali was for experienced Linux users?

Comment: There Is one prompt appearing just for two-three seconds then disappearing.
And No Ctrl-altF1 or F2  is not helping. And by the way, I have already installed Kali already twice because of this issue and I am trying this all to use Kali and learn to use it properly and get some experience. Getting Me?

Comment: Basics: kali is based on debian, so remedies present for debian and ubuntu may well work. Ubuntu has a "Recovery mode" in the grub boot menu. You might have that in kali too; hit ESC once as the bios text disappears during boot,. Google e.g. "ubuntu recovery mode" for more detail.

Comment: Not helping, it is doing all the recovery and all showing tons of lines saying everything is ok and then again loading a black screen with blinking cursor

Comment: I again installed kali and ran this command
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
then it asked me to restart some services then again went black screen with blinking cursor